# How can I get information about different type of pages of a Shopify App?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I need to know on which type of page I am on in a Shopify App. For example

```
% if template contains 'product' %}
  {% assign entity = product %}
{% elsif template contains 'article' %}
  {% assign entity = article %}
{% endif %}
```

This in a liquid page tell me about `product` and `article` pages. What are such tags for say `category` page or `home` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`template`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/template) variable tells you the name of the template for the current page. For example, your home page is **index.liquid** so on that page `{{ template }}` will output `index` (the name of the template without ".liquid" extension).

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, thanks. But can I get the category pages from somewhere? For example if a shop has, let's say, Apparels or Laptops in the category, how do I get that?

Comment: If you want all the collections in a shop, there's the [`collections` global object](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects#global-objects) (accessible from any file). If you are on a collection page, you can access the current [`collection`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/collection) with `collection.handle` or `collection.title`.